# I want to bind dynamic <ul> to a dynamically created <html> table

Tags: html, jquery

I want to bind dynamic `<ul>` to a dynamically created `<html>` table. The first image is correct as per the code.

[image]

the image shown below is perfect with the code below,

```
    $("#forbtn").click(function()    
    {
      
        $.ajax({
            url: "json/animals.json",
            dataType : "json",
            type:"post",
            success : function(data) {
               
               //console.log(data);                    

               //const myobj = JSON.parse(data);
               //console.log(myobj);

               var myobj = data;

               var tabdata = myobj.length;
               var tablebody = '<table border="1" width="100%"><thead><tr><th class="tabhead"> Name </th><th class="tabhead"> Species </th><th class="tabhead"> Foods </th></tr></thead><tbody>';
               for (i=0 ; i < myobj.length; i++)
               {
                    tablebody += '<tr>';
                    tablebody += '<td class="tabdat">';
                    tablebody += myobj[i].name;
                    tablebody += '</td>';
                    tablebody += '<td class="tabdat">';
                    tablebody += myobj[i].species;
                    tablebody += '</td>';
                    tablebody += '<td class="tabdat">'
                    tablebody += myobj[i].foods;                                     
                    tablebody += '</td>';
               }
               tablebody += '</tbody></table>';
               $("#table2").html(tablebody);
               $("#table2").css({"margin-top" : "10px"});    
               $("#table2 .tabhead").css({"padding":"5px" , "background-color" : "#E6E6E6"});
               $("#table2 .tabdat").css({"padding":"5px" , "background-color" : "#FAFAFA"});
            }
        });
    });
```

However, I need something like this, I had tried to include `<ul>` in the mentioned `<td>` but it's giving a syntax error of for loop. I don't understand whats wrong in the for loop syntax.

[image]
[image: enter code here]

```
$.ajax({
            url: "json/animals.json",
            dataType : "json",
            type:"post",
            success : function(data) {
               
               //console.log(data);                    

               //const myobj = JSON.parse(data);
               //console.log(myobj);

               var myobj = data;

               var tabdata = myobj.length;
               var tablebody = '<table border="1" width="100%"><thead><tr><th class="tabhead"> Name </th><th class="tabhead"> Species </th><th class="tabhead"> Foods </th></tr></thead><tbody>';
               for (i=0 ; i < myobj.length; i++)
               {
                    tablebody += '<tr>';
                    tablebody += '<td class="tabdat">';
                    tablebody += myobj[i].name;
                    tablebody += '</td>';
                    tablebody += '<td class="tabdat">';
                    tablebody += myobj[i].species;
                    tablebody += '</td>';
                    tablebody += '<td class="tabdat">'
                                 '<ul><li>'  for(j=0 ; j<myobj[i].foods.likes.length; j++)  
                                 {
                                    myobj[i].foods.likes[j];
                                 } '<li></ul>';
                    tablebody += '</td>';
               }
               tablebody += '</tbody></table>';
               $("#table2").html(tablebody);
               $("#table2").css({"margin-top" : "10px"});    
               $("#table2 .tabhead").css({"padding":"5px" , "background-color" : "#E6E6E6"});
               $("#table2 .tabdat").css({"padding":"5px" , "background-color" : "#FAFAFA"});
            }
        });
```

here is the json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Meowsy",
    "species" : "cat",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["tuna", "catnip"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Barky",
    "species" : "dog",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["bones", "carrots"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Purrpaws",
    "species" : "cat",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["mice" , "milk"]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: *"I want to bind dynamic to a dynamically created table"* What do you mean by this? Do you have click events that don't register on dynamically created elements?

Comment: @Martin was badly formatted - tags not escaped - it's "*bind dynamic `<ul>` to dynamically created `<html>` table*" - of course, still no idea what that actually means...

Comment: The "syntax error in the for loop" is because you've stuck a for loop in the middle of a string concat - that's not how for loops work.

Comment: Your problem begins here: `tablebody += '<td class="tabdat">'` you're not closing your string concatenation. Then you have to perform your loop and concatenate inside that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
 tablebody += '<td class="tabdat">'
              '<ul><li>'  for(j=0 ; j<myobj[i].foods.likes.length; j++)  
                          {
                              myobj[i].foods.likes[j];
                          } '<li></ul>';
```

Needs to be reformatted to:

```
 tablebody += '<td class="tabdat">';
 tablebody += '<ul>';
 for (j=0; j < myobj[i].foods.likes.length; j++)  
 {
     tablebody += '<li>' + myobj[i].foods.likes[j] + '</li>';
 } 
 tablebody += '</ul>';
```

There are other ways such as using `join`, but this shows how to add a for loop inside your string concat.

Comment: You're missing semi-colon on `tablebody += '<li>' + myobj[i].foods.likes[j] + '</li>'`

Comment: @Martin "closing tag"?  you mean semi-colon?  That's not actually *required* there

Comment: Semi-colon, yes.

Comment: Awesome ! It worked.  Thanks freedom-m.   Thanks Martin.
will remember not to include for loop in the middle of string concat.